# Eternal loop in a simple HTML-form-creating loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I'm trying to make this simple code of creating 3 multiple-choice question out of a JSON data,
For reason beyond my comprehension what happens is an eternal loop, in which the last question is written to the page again and again until it crashes...
Help and advice would be highly appreciated.

```
var questions = {
"qestion":["what is bla?", "what is bla bla?", "what is bla bla bla?"],
"answer":[["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd"], ["eee","fff","ggg","hhh"], ["zzz","xxx","yyy","www"]],
"correctAns":[1,2,3]};

String.prototype.format = function() {
    var formatted = this;
    for (i=0; i< arguments.length; i++) {
        var regexp = new RegExp('\\{'+i+'\\}', 'gi');
        formatted = formatted.replace(regexp, arguments[i]);
        }
    return formatted;
};

function writeQuestions() {

    for (i=0 ;i<=2; i++) {

            answerRdy = [];
            qestionRdy = questions.qestion[i];
            answerRdy[0] = questions.answer[i][0];
            answerRdy[1] = questions.answer[i][1];
            answerRdy[2] = questions.answer[i][2];
            answerRdy[3] = questions.answer[i][3];
            divID = "question-" + i;

                writeAnswer = [];
                writeAnswer[writeAnswer.length] = ("\n<div id='{0}'>\n<form method='post' onsubmit='return validate(this);'>\n").format(divID);
                writeAnswer[writeAnswer.length] = ("<b>" + qestionRdy + "</b><br />\n");
            for (n=0; n<=3; n++) {
                writeAnswer[writeAnswer.length] = ("<input type='radio' name='answer' value='{0}' /> {1} <br />\n").format(n, answerRdy[n]);
                    }
                writeAnswer[writeAnswer.length] = ("<input type='submit' value='Submit your answer'>\n</form>\n</div><!--{0}-->").format(divID);


            joinQuestion = writeAnswer.join();
                exp = /,/gi;
            fullQuestion = joinQuestion.replace(exp, "");

        $('#container').append(fullQuestion);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed you for loops to declare local variables for iteration and also linked the  termination length to the appropriate object and that seemed to do the trick.  For example:

```
for (i=0 ;i<=2; i++) {
```

became:

```
for (var i = 0, len = questions.answer.length; i < len; i++) {
```

[See example →](http://jsfiddle.net/pNZ5A/)

Comment: Thanx, but which i should i change? the String.prototype.format or writeQuestions()?

Answer (score 1):

Could it because your have two for loops that use an un-declared magic global variable "i"

```
for (i=0...
```

where it should most likely be

```
for (var i=0...
```